# JavaFX TilePane setPrefColumn/Row methods not working?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I'm trying to make a Suduko board in JavaFX. I heard TilePane is especially good for this because the entire idea behind TilePane is that each 'Tile' is of uniform size. Great, that's exactly how a Suduko board, chess board, checkers, Tic Tac Toe, Battleship, etc. Sounds like TilePane is the must have pane for any kind of board game app.

Or is it?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter.Change;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SudukoSolver extends Application
{
    Stage window;
    Scene scene;
    private final int TEXTFIELD_WIDTH = 32;
    private final int TEXTFIELD_HEIGHT = 32;

    @Override public void start(Stage window) throws Exception
    {       
        this.window = window;
        window.setTitle("Suduko Solver");
        window.setOnCloseRequest(e -> closeProgram());

        // Does setting this to false defeat the purpose of TilePane?
        window.setResizable(false); 

        VBox root = new VBox(); 
        //root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        TilePane tiles = new TilePane();    
        tiles.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        // Does not appear to do anything.
        tiles.setPrefColumns(9);
        tiles.setPrefRows(9);

        // Add all the tiles to the Pane.
        root.getChildren().add(tiles);

        for (int i = 0; i < 81; i++)
        {
            TextField textBox = new TextField();
            textBox.setMinHeight(TEXTFIELD_HEIGHT);
            textBox.setMaxHeight(TEXTFIELD_HEIGHT);
            textBox.setMinWidth(TEXTFIELD_WIDTH);
            textBox.setMaxWidth(TEXTFIELD_WIDTH);

            textBox.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<String>((Change change) -> 
            {
                String newText = change.getControlNewText();
                if (newText.length() > 1) 
                {
                    return null ;
                }
                else if (newText.matches("[^1-9]"))
                {
                    return null;
                }
                else 
                {
                    return change ;
                }
            }));

            tiles.getChildren().add(textBox);
        }


        scene = new Scene(root, 600, 750);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called when the user wishes to close the program.
     */
    private void closeProgram()
    {
        Platform.exit();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Notice how clearly this is not a 9x9 grid.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code the width of your `TilePane` is determided by the parent `VBox` rather than by the `prefColumns` property of the `TilePane`.

From the [javadoc of `prefColumns`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/TilePane.html#prefColumnsProperty):

> This value is used only to compute the preferred size of the tilepane and may not reflect the actual number of <strike>rows</strike> columns, which may change if the tilepane is resized to something other than its preferred <strike>height</strike> width.

(Some errors in the doc fixed by me.)

You need to use a parent that doesn't resize the `TilePane`. (`VBox` resizes it's children by default.) Use [`VBox.setFillWidth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/VBox.html#setFillWidth-boolean-) to change this behaviour:

```
root.setFillWidth(false);
```